# Dynamically creating models in django to be used in a unit test

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a test model in a unit test so that I can test associated behavior. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#isolating-model-registration) and related questions here on SO, both indicate that I should use the `isolate_apps` utility function, that in theory should register a temporary app which holds my test model. Note that I'm on django v1.11. My test looks like this:

```
from django.test.utils import isolate_apps
from django.db import models
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @isolate_apps("app_label")
    def test_the_model(self):
        class TestModel(models.Model):
            field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I'm not even running any assertions because it fails before.

#### Error stack trace

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:381: in inner
    with self as context:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:353: in __enter__
    return self.enable()
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:878: in enable
    apps = Apps(self.installed_apps)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:56: in __init__
    self.populate(installed_apps)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:85: in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py:94: in create
    module = import_module(entry)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

name = 'app_label', package = None

    def import_module(name, package=None):
        """Import a module.
    
        The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
        specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
        relative import to an absolute import.
    
        """
        level = 0
        if name.startswith('.'):
            if not package:
                msg = ("the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative "
                       "import for {!r}")
                raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
            for character in name:
                if character != '.':
                    break
                level += 1
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_label'

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: ModuleNotFoundError
```

It seems like the utility function is not actually creating the virtual app as needed, leading to the import error. At least, that's what my understanding is. The documentation doesn't mention any pre-setup, but maybe I'm missing that? Maybe something related to `INSTALLED_APPS`.